# exporting POD_HOST + random_string as an environment variable in a pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am writing a statefulset and I need to export the POD_HOST+abc as an environment variable.
The second environment variable should be named differently from the POD_HOST

I did something like

```
      env:
        - name: POD_HOST
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              fieldPath: metadata.name
        - name: POD_FULL_NAME
          value: $POD_HOST"abc"
```

which I can see as being exported in the environment as $POD_HOST"abc". Is there a way I can make the POD_HOST resolved in the kubernetes pod before being exported in the environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use parentheses for using environment variable inside environment variable.

Example :

```
      env:
      - name: POD_HOST
        valueFrom:
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.name
      - name: POD_FULL_NAME
        value: $(POD_HOST)-abc
```